# greatest common divisor Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, greatest-common-divisor

I am new to ios programing. I have question about the GCD program.

```
01 // This program finds the greatest common divisor of two nonnegative integer values
02 
03 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
04 
05 int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
06     NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
07     unsigned int u, v, temp;
08     
09     NSLog(@"Please type in two nonnegative integers.");
10     scanf("%u%u", &u, &v);
11     
12     while (v != 0) {
13         temp = u % v;
14         u = v;
15         v = temp;
16     }
17     
18     NSLog(@"Their greatest common divisor is %u", u);
19     
20     [pool drain];
21     return 0;
22 }
```

I don't understand  this part:

```
while(v!=0)
     temp = u%v
     u =v;
     v = temp;
```

What does that mean, in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% is the [mod operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_operator). Those three lines divide `u` by `v` and store the remainder in temp. Then `u` gets the value of `v`, and `v` gets the remainder. The process is repeated while `v` is not 0.

Answer (score 2):

That part actually calculates the greatest common divisor using the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Greatest_common_divisor).

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using euclideans algorithm

as you can see, `temp = u%v` % is a modulo operator where it divides the u and v and the remainder of it is stored at temp. then the value of is stored at the variable v and lastly the value of temp is stored at the variable v. and this whole process will repeat until the value of v is not equal to 0 or not 0.